# Error for creating a simple random number

Tags: javascript, random

So I am trying to set a simple variable as a random number, but I keep getting an error. I'm using https://thimble.mozilla.org/ to run my code but it keeps giving me an error.

my code is:

```
var x = randomNumber(1,6)

console.log(x);
```

I've tried putting in and taking out a semicolon at the end of line 1

Comment: Why you think there's a `randomNumber(min, max)` function?

Comment: code.org as well as my teacher said that there is

Comment: There's "only" [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: oh... I guess they were wrong then? thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

general formula for generating random number between a lower and upper bound.  (keep in mind that Math.random is a pseudo random number generator)

```js
let lower = 1
let upper = 6;
let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (upper - lower + 1) + lower);
console.log(x)
```